# Multiplying Contents of list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell and am trying to implement a function that returns the contents of a list multiplied together. Here is my code:

```
product' :: Num a => [a] -> a
product' [] = 1
product' (_:xs) = foldl (*) 1 xs
```

In the command line, I type product in:

```
product' [2,3,4]
```

and I get 12 instead of 24. I know it has to do with the first element of the list not being read, but I cannot figure it out. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you omit the first element by _?

Comment: @qxg I did not know their was a difference between _ and using the variable x.

Comment: _ means unused variable.

Comment: @qxg Gotcha. That makes more sense now. Both ways work perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no particular difference between using `_` and using `x` in your provided implementation. `_` does formally require that the parameter be unused, but renaming it to `x` won't cause it to be used if you don't refer to it!

Comment: @amalloy That makes sense now and is clearer going into the future. Thank you for the explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

```
product' :: Num a => [a] -> a
product' = foldl (*) 1
```

or

```
product' :: Num a => [a] -> a
product' [] = 1
product' (x:xs) = foldl (*) x xs
```

if you wish to keep parameter.

Comment: That second equation isn't quite right. The product of an empty collection is `1`, just like its sum is `0`, because they are identities. You don't handle that case.

Comment: I was actually thinking about just pointing the first equation to `product' xs = foldl (*) 1 xs`, but that works too.